# Python parsing xml to dataframe without disctinctly named TAGs

Tags: python, xml, pandas

I've been passed a bunch of XML files, however the tags don't have distinct names, rather, all the the record tags ends with  rather than the opening name.  It looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0'  encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<RESULTS>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN NAME="CASE_KEY"><![CDATA[1248999]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="CASE_DESCRIPTION">[CDATA[MANUAL-GP-[][][02]01 JUL</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="CASE_NARRATIVE"> doing my narrative</COLUMN>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN NAME="CASE_KEY"><![CDATA[1248998]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="CASE_DESCRIPTION">[CDATA[MANUAL-GP-[][][02]01 AUG</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="CASE_NARRATIVE">another narative stuff</COLUMN>
    </ROW>
</RESULTS>
```

So you can see the root is , and each RECORD is named .  That I can work with.  Each of the embedded tags ends with  though, and I think this is screwing up my code.  Here is what I've got:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as et
import pandas as pd

def getvalueofnode(node):
    """ return node text or None """
    return node.text if node is not None else None


def main():
    """ main """
    parsed_xml = et.parse("Load.xml")
    dfcols = ['ROW','CASE_KEY','CASE_DESCRIPTION','CASE_NARRATIVE']
    df_xml = pd.DataFrame(columns=dfcols)

    for node in parsed_xml.getroot():
        ROW = node.attrib.get('ROW')
        CASE_KEY = node.find('CASE_KEY')
        CASE_DESCRIPTION = node.find('CASE_DESCRIPTION')
        CASE_NARRATIVE = node.find('CASE_NARRATIVE')

        df_xml = df_xml.append(
            pd.Series([ROW, getvalueofnode(CASE_KEY), getvalueofnode(CASE_DESCRIPTION),
                       getvalueofnode(CASE_NARRATIVE)], index=dfcols),
            ignore_index=True)

    print(df_xml)

main()
```

Here is the output from what I've run:

```
\c:\python\MonitorScripts\xmlcleaner\NewXML\Alerts>"c:\python\MonitorScripts\xmlcleaner\xmlc.py"
    ROW CASE_KEY CASE_DESCRIPTION CASE_NARRATIVE
0  None     None             None           None
```

I'm guessing it's the strangely named tags that's messing me about, however I have no option to change them to properly formatted tags.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What constitutes a record in the above? Each row? And are you after extracting per row CASE_KEY, CASE_DESCRIPTION, CASE_NARRATIVE ?

Comment: Yes, each ROW.  Yes, extracting those 3 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used attribute = value css selectors with bs4

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
doc = """
<?xml version='1.0'  encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<RESULTS>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN NAME="CASE_KEY"><![CDATA[1248999]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="CASE_DESCRIPTION">[CDATA[MANUAL-GP-[][][02]01 JUL</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="CASE_NARRATIVE"> doing my narrative</COLUMN>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN NAME="CASE_KEY"><![CDATA[1248998]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="CASE_DESCRIPTION">[CDATA[MANUAL-GP-[][][02]01 AUG</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="CASE_NARRATIVE">another narative stuff</COLUMN>
    </ROW>
</RESULTS>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, 'html.parser')

caseKeys = [case.text for case in soup.select('[name="CASE_KEY"]')]
caseDescriptions = [case.text for case in soup.select('[name="CASE_DESCRIPTION"]')]
caseNarratives = [case.text for case in soup.select('[name="CASE_NARRATIVE"]')]
results = list(zip(caseKeys, caseDescriptions, caseNarratives))
df = pd.DataFrame(results,columns = ['CaseKey','CaseDescription','CaseNarrative'])
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `objectify`:

```
from lxml import objectify

xml = objectify.parse('file.xml')
root = xml.getroot()

data=[]
for i in range(len(root.getchildren())):
    data.append([child.text for child in root.getchildren()[i].getchildren()])

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['CASE_KEY', 'CASE_DESCRIPTION', 'CASE_NARRATIVE']
```

Comment: I like this.  It's elegant.  Will do a performance test on the two.